# Shrinking webpages that are shown in your UIWebviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app I load some webpages in a 480*320(landscape) UIWebView. But the text is too large, well really the whole content of the page is too big.

Is there some trick that you can do to scale down the whole page in the web view so that it does not seem completely out of proportion to the rest of the app?

I'm guessing there is not and that the only way is to get the HTML of the whole page and look for Font tags and change them all to something smaller and then loading it into a UIWebView.

Thanks for any suggestions or ideas you can offer,
-Code

Comment: @Brian Lyttle: that was a funny edit summary `:)`

Comment: If you have access to the HTML page(s) that you are loading in/viewing, I suppose you could accomplish the resizing task with a quick CSS edit or quickly create a special mobile-friendly version of the page?

Comment: You can call `[myYebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];` Does that help?

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but you could also set the property like this: myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

Comment: Yep, that is just dot syntax vs square bracket syntax. Both create the same result.

Comment: @e.James Your answer was correct. Put it in an answer and I will accept it for future readers to see. Thanks -Code :)

Comment: @Code: Hooray for good guesses `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UIWebView` property `scalesPagesToFit` should work:

```
myYebView.scalesPagesToFit = YES;
```

From the [UIWebView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> You can also use the [scalesPageToFit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/scalesPageToFit) property to programmatically set the scale of web content the first time it is displayed in a web view. Thereafter, the user can change the scale using gestures.